# How fix this error running react-native run android

Tags: react-native

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Oniva\Aplicações\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Oniva\Aplicações\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Oniva\Aplica��es\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Oniva\AplicaÃ§Ãµes\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Oniva\Aplicações\app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.

Comment: delete `node_module` and `yarn.lock` folder and run this command `npm i` or `yarn install` ... and run your project again ...

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling & re-installing the `node_modules`.

Go to the project root and execute the below commands.

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`
3. `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the special characters in my path.
Try to put your project inside a folder that does not have any spaces or special characters.